# C# convert string into jagged arrays of ints

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio

I have problem with converting string into jagged array of ints. I tryed using linq but can't get it work. Any suggestions how can i do it?

```
String Numbers = "[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]";
        String [][] myStrings = output.Text.Split(']').Select(t => t.Split(',')).ToArray();
        int[][] ints = Array.ConvertAll(myStrings, t => int.Parse(t));
```

Comment: Probably because your split output is not comprised of elements that can all be converted to int.  Put a breakpoint and inspect `myStrings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking something like this:

```
 var re= Numbers.Split(new[] { "] " },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(s => s.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',').Select(st=>int.Parse(st)).ToArray())
                .ToArray();
```

First split the string array representation, then remove the brackets and split by ',', and finally cast each element of the `string` collection to `int` and call `ToArray` extension method.

Answer (score 1):

it seems Parse doesn't work because of `]` and `[` symbols

```
String Numbers = "[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]";

int [][] ints = 
    Numbers.Trim(']','[').Split(new [] {"] ["}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(t => t.Split(',').Select(s=>int.Parse(s)).ToArray())
           .ToArray();
```

try this sample with a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/17GZPb)